# How to learn a wireless router's MAC address

Tags: macos, network

I am using Mac OS X Lion. How can I learn the MAC address of a wireless router that is listed in the wireless network list?

Answer (score 12):

Option-click on the Wi-Fi icon. Once the menu appears, press Option again. Now when you hover over any network a tooltip with the MAC address (BSSID) will appear after a short delay.

Comment: That's not the right procedure. The correct method is to hold the OPTION key and then right click on the WiFi icon. It'll then show details of the current network you are connected to (but not the others). To find information about the other networks, you would click the OPTION key again and then, like you say, hover over them, which will prompt a tooltip with the information (you need only click OPTION again one time to prompts). An Option-click (or Alt-click) signifies a click of the right mouse button. Can you please fix your terminology? It is a little ambiguous and may confuse some users.

Comment: Only Ctrl-click is a direct equivalent of right-click. I definitely do not have to right-click the icon while holding down the option key for this to work. But yes, once Option is pressed again the tooltip occurs for every network, I'll this in a minute.

Comment: Sorry, that should be left click, not alt-click (right click); just a normal click... sigh.

Answer (score 5):

We can use the `system_profiler` command.

```bash
system_profiler  SPNetworkDataType | grep RouterHardwareAddress
```

Sample output:

```
Network Signature: IPv4.Router=10.104.26.1;IPv4.RouterHardwareAddress=00:10:db:ff:81:70
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way out is you can get the MAC address associated with an IP address. In your case, you need to find your router's IP address. Normally, it's your Default Gateway. You can do all of these using the command lines.

First, you need to get your Default Gateway. Type `netstat -nr | grep default`. The output should show something like this:

```
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           31        0     en1
```

From that, you could pretty sure that your router's IP address is `192.168.1.1`. Then, you must find the MAC address associated to this IP by using `arp -a | grep 192.168.1.1` command. The output will show you the router's MAC address.

```
? (192.168.1.1) at 0:c:42:64:bd:10 on en1 ifscope ...
```

Hope that help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Get the router's IP first, then use `arp -a` to find out the MAC address.

You can get the router's IP by this command

```
echo "show State:/Network/Global/IPv4" | scutil | grep Router
```

or

```
ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep router
```

**Method 2:**

Get the service UUID of your Wi-Fi first

```
echo "show State:/Network/Global/IPv4" | scutil | grep PrimaryService
```

then get the MAC address by the service UUID

```
echo "show State:/Network/Service/<service UUID>/IPv4" | scutil | grep ARPResolvedHardwareAddress
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. Your “below works” example using ipconfig and the scutil example shows an IPv4 address for me and not the media access control hardware address. Can you update your answer to link together reading the arp table to answer the MAC address portion of the question? The existing answer from 2011 has details about reading the arp table

Comment: @bmike answer updated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this free tool to discover the MAC address

http://www.istumbler.net/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. Can you tell us why you like the app? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.